# What syntax allows the condition in OpenOffice's SUMIF function to match a regular expression in a different cell?

Tags: openoffice-calc

What syntax allows the condition in OpenOffice's `SUMIF` function to match a regular expression in a different cell?

For example, suppose the cell A1 contains a regular expression. How must the question marks in the example below be replaced so that the condition for summing up uses the regex in A1?

```
SUMIF(A23:A240,??,B23:B240)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`SUMIF(test_range; condition; sum_range)`](http://wiki.services.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/How_Tos/Calc:_SUMIF_function) supports regular expressions if you have enabled that option. See [Regular expressions in Calc](http://wiki.services.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/How_Tos/Regular_Expressions_in_Calc)

[image: Enabling Regular Expressions in Calc]

If the cell `A1` contains a regular expression, then you can simply use:

```
SUMIF(A23:A240, A1, B23:B240)
```

The `condition` parameter can be cell reference, a number or string to match or an expression to match its value. It can also be a string that starts with a comparison operator.

```
SUMIF(A23:A240, "<0", B23:B240)
```

would sum the numbers in the second range for corresponding cells in the first range that are less than zero.

```
SUMIF(A23:A240, "truck", B23:B240)
```

would sum the numbers in the second range for corresponding cells in the first range that are less than zero.

Please see [Conditional Counting and Summation in Calc](http://wiki.services.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/How_Tos/Conditional_Counting_and_Summation) for more information.